# Why does my .NET rest API return a list with extra childproperty instead of [..]?

Tags: c#, json, list, asp.net-web-api

I've been wondering for a while now why:

```
public List<int> getTest(){
   List<int> test = new List<int>();
   test.add(1);
   return test;
}
```

returns to clientside as:

```
{
   test: {
            $id: randomnumber,
            $values: [1]
         }
}
```

Instead of

```
{
   test: [1]
}
```

I use .NET framework 4.6.1 and initialize the list just like the code above. Usually it is not a problem because in clientside you can acces $values as easily as test. But I can't let go of wondering why it returns like this. And hope someone can give me a relieving answer on why and if it is possible to return without an extra child property $values and $id.

The function gets called in a controller class from an implementation class.

```
        [HttpGet, Route("getTest")]
        public List<int> getTest()
        {
            return implementationClass.getTest();
        }
```

Comment: Show us where getTest() is getting called?

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain Ty for reply, edited the main question.

Comment: Is this WebAPI2 or ASP.NET Core? Have you configured your JSON serialiser settings? If so, what did you do?

Comment: @DavidG We use Web API 2, this is how the JSON serialiser settings are configured in Application_Start(): 'var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;'

Comment: Well `PreserveReferencesHandling.All` is why you get output like this. Remove that line and it will look much better.

Comment: @DavidG Thank you, commenting out the JSON serialiser settings actually answered my question! Put it as answer and ill vote as accepted answer. Is it possible to configure the JSON serialiser settings for a specific request that you might know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have configured your JSON serialisation settings to use [`PreserveReferencesHandling.all`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm), that is why your output is very different than you expect. For example:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

var json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All });
```

Will give you these 2 variants of JSON output:

```
[1,2,3]
{"$id":"1","$values":[1,2,3]}
```

So you can either remove than configuration or, if you specifically want to change it just for this method, you will have to manually do the conversion, for example:

```
public string getTest()
{
   List<int> test = new List<int>();
   test.add(1);
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In DotNet, you will always get the metadata properties for complex types.

To clean your Json result add json ignore attributes
like:

```
options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles
```

Read more in the official documentation from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-6-0).

Answer (score -1):

Use This.

```
    [HttpGet, Route("getTest")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get ()
    {
       return Ok(implementationClass.getTest());  // Returns an OkNegotiatedContentResult
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think this will help?

Comment: Because it will return the JSON response.

Comment: It is already returning JSON response. This change will have absolutely no effect.